# Creating a Site (Develop>Sites) with customized Guest User Profile via the Metadata API

Tags: force.com-sites, metadata-api

Use case: We have a managed package installed from the AppExchange with a Setup Wizard. As part of the Setup Wizard, we'd like to utilize the Metadata API to:
1) Create a Site
2) Customize the Site's Profile (Guest User License, declaratively accessed via Public Access Settings button) to have:
A- A defined Apex Class
B- Object permissions
C- Field level permissions

We found how to make the Site: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sites.htm, but not how to customize the Profile data.

Ideas?